# Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable $N$ times

Tags: calculus

> Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(b^n x)}{a^n}$$ where $a>1, b>0$ and there's an $N$ such that $b^N < a$. Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable $N$ times in the interval $(0,1)$.

So first I've showed that $f(x)$ converges uniformly to some $f$ by Weierstrass M-test:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(b^nx)}{a^n} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^nx}{a^n} \le \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{b^nx}{a^n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{b^nx}{a^n} \le C + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{ax}{a^n} \\ \le C + x \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^{n-1}} \lt \infty$$

Therefore, 
$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{\sin b^nx}{a^n} \right)' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (b^nx)x}{a^n}$$

Now, should I just keep this process again? 
I'm not so sure about that...

Comment: First things first: $$\left(\sin(b^nx)\over a^n\right)'={b^n\cos(b^nx)\over a^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, set $N=1$. If $N>1$, the situation is the same. Let 
$$ S_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin(b^nx)}{a^n}. $$
Then $S_n(x)$ is differentiable and converges uniformly to $f(x)$. Moreover $S'_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{b^n\sin(b^nx)}{a^n}$ converges uniformly in[0,1]. From Walter Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd Edition, Theorem 7.17, we have
$$ f'(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N'(x).$$
Namely
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b^n\sin(b^nx)}{a^n}.$$